# Kendo UI MVVM data binding with JayData

Tags: mvvm, kendo-ui, jaydata

i am new to as a whole (Kendo UI && MVVM).

I am trying to bind a drop down list with a local database, and its throwing an error on the line marked //<<<<<<

What am I doing wrong here? - I have seen the example that is available on JayData but it doesn't give a clear idea of how to bind local db.

My code looks like this.

```
 <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="NESTForm">

            <select data-role="dropdownlist" data-value-field="UserID" data-text-field="Name"
                data-bind="source: userSource">
            </select>



        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var userDB;
        $(document).ready(function () {


            $data.Entity.extend("Users",
            {
                UserID: { type: "int", key: true, required: true },
                Name: { type: "string", required: true }

            });


            $data.EntityContext.extend("EXAMPLEDB", {
                Users: { type: $data.EntitySet, elementType: Users }
            });

            userDB = new EXAMPLEDB({
                name: "webSql", databaseName: "EXMPLEDB",
                dbCreation: $data.storageProviders.DbCreationType.DropTableIfChange
            });


            var viewModel = kendo.observable({

                //Initial data  binders   ,
                userSource: userDB.Users.asKendoDataSource() //<<<<<< this throws error



            });

            // apply the bindings
            kendo.bind(document.body.children, viewModel);

        });

    </script>
```

The error is

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){var c=this,d,e;c.trigger(w,{field:a}),a==="this"?d=c:(e=O[a]=O[a]||n.getter(a,!0),d=e(c),b&&typeof d=="function"&&(d=d.call(c)));return d} has no method 'push'
```

Answer (score 2):

Well I posted the same question on JayData forum and figured out. Although I downloaded the package from Jaydata the script files were old, the community suggested me to link to script directly at SVN

Just for the sake of record, the code above works fine.

here is the community reply

http://jaydata.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=174&sid=2ff7d9f37bf758a573c70a89fac507fb

Answer (score 0):

I can not try it now, it looks ok except that you have to wait for your db to get ready, something like:

```
userDB.onReady(function() {
var viewModel = ...
```